# Google Jam test cases passes but submission shows "Wrong Answer"

Tags: python, google-code

> Note: The main parts of the statements of the problems "Reversort" and
> "Reversort Engineering" are identical, except for the last paragraph.
> The problems can otherwise be solved independently.
>
> Reversort is an algorithm to sort a list of distinct integers in
> increasing order. The algorithm is based on the "Reverse" operation.
> Each application of this operation reverses the order of some
> contiguous part of the list.
>
> After i−1 iterations, the positions 1,2,…,i−1 of the list contain the
> i−1 smallest elements of L, in increasing order. During the i-th
> iteration, the process reverses the sublist going from the i-th
> position to the current position of the i-th minimum element. That
> makes the i-th minimum element end up in the i-th position.
>
> For example, for a list with 4 elements, the algorithm would perform 3
> iterations. Here is how it would process L=[4,2,1,3]:
>
> i=1, j=3⟶L=[1,2,4,3] i=2, j=2⟶L=[1,2,4,3] i=3, j=4⟶L=[1,2,3,4] The
> most expensive part of executing the algorithm on our architecture is
> the Reverse operation. Therefore, our measure for the cost of each
> iteration is simply the length of the sublist passed to Reverse, that
> is, the value j−i+1. The cost of the whole algorithm is the sum of the
> costs of each iteration.
>
> In the example above, the iterations cost 3, 1, and 2, in that order,
> for a total of 6.
>
> Given the initial list, compute the cost of executing Reversort on it.
>
> Input The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T
> test cases follow. Each test case consists of 2 lines. The first line
> contains a single integer N, representing the number of elements in
> the input list. The second line contains N distinct integers L1, L2,
> ..., LN, representing the elements of the input list L, in order.
>
> Output For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y,
> where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the total
> cost of executing Reversort on the list given as input.
>
> Limits Time limit: 10 seconds. Memory limit: 1 GB. Test Set 1 (Visible
> Verdict) 1≤T≤100. 2≤N≤100. 1≤Li≤N, for all i. Li≠Lj, for all i≠j.
> Sample Sample Input 3 4 4 2 1 3 2 1 2 7 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 Sample Output
> Case #1: 6 Case #2: 1 Case #3: 12 Sample Case #1 is described in the
> statement above.
>
> In Sample Case #2, there is a single iteration, in which Reverse is
> applied to a sublist of size 1. Therefore, the total cost is 1.
>
> In Sample Case #3, the first iteration reverses the full list, for a
> cost of 7. After that, the list is already sorted, but there are 5
> more iterations, each of which contributes a cost of 1.

```
def Reversort(L):
    sort = 0
    for i in range(len(L)-1):
        small = L[i]
        x = L[i]
        y = L[i]
        for j in range(i, len(L)):
            if L[j] < small :
                small = L[j]
        sort = sort + (L.index(small) - L.index(y) + 1) 
        L[L.index(small)] = x
        L[L.index(y)] = small
        print(L) #For debugging purpose
    return sort

T = int(input())
for i in range(T):
    N = int(input())
    L = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    s = Reversort(L)
    print(f"Case #{i+1}: {s}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails for the test case 7 6 5 4 3 2 1. The code gives the answer as 18 whereas the answer should be 12.

You have forgotten to reverse the list between i and j.

the algorithm says

> During the i-th iteration, the process reverses the sublist going from the i-th position to the current position of the i-th minimum element.

Comment: I did reverse it accordingly. It just happens that the problem occurs at case 3.
Here's the debugging ss
https://imgur.com/a/5jvGzi7